# Implementation of webhook in Azure Data Factory

Tags: .net, azure, azure-data-factory

I am having difficulties in getting the callback URI from azure data factory when using webhook activity also I am currently calling webjob within the webhook. Inside the webjob I have .Net code but I am not able to get the callback URI.

And I really need to use the the webhook activity because I have a long running job

Comment: Thank you for correcting my spelling mistakes!

Answer (score 3):

Based on this very detailed explanation from this [blog](https://mrpaulandrew.com/2019/06/18/azure-data-factory-web-hook-vs-web-activity/) and interesting example in this [link](https://vanishedgradient.com/2019/04/25/webhooks-with-azure-data-factory/), at the time of invocation of webhook activity in a pipeline, Data Factory will add an additional field to the JSON body of the request, “callBackUri”, which will be automatically created.(If not,you could set it in the body by youself)

From there you can choose to continue executing in the pipeline, or use Data Factory’s control flows to gracefully handle a failure, or timeout.

[image]

---

Update Answer:

Based on your latest comment,i assume that you want to pass a callbackuri as a parameter into webjob and use it in the webjob inside.

I searched the WebJob REST APi, and got this [api](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job):`/api/triggeredwebjobs/{job name}/run?arguments={arguments}`

> To run with arguments use the arguments parameters that will be added
>   to the script when invoked. It also gets passed to the WebJob as the
>   WEBJOBS_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS environment variable

It seems that WebJob only accepts command arguments, so i did a test with a simple Console App.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JayWebJobConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write(args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then i invoke the above rest api by `https://***.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/WebJob1/run?arguments=jayuri`,it could be printed in the log:

[image]

I also did a test that passing the jayuri in the body but it can't be touched.

[image]

So i'm afraid that you have to pass the `callbackuri` just behind the webhook uri like uri/arguments=callbackuri as same as my test.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. First of all, I have already seen this post before, which did not help much, because either they are using logic apps or azure functions, but I want to invoke the callBackUri from a .Net console app which is deployed as a webjob. So, from the webhook activity when I call the webjob, I am sure it passes the callBackUri in the post method but I am not sure how can I get that URI in my Console App.

If you can provide any reference related to .Net, then it would be highly helpful.

Comment: @sabs773 Maybe i'm confused here about your requirement.Firstly,based on my understanding of this callbackUri in webhook activity, it is used to be invoked after the process of webjob. However,you described in your comment that you want to pass this callbackUri as a parameter into webjob and want to use it in your webjob,am i right?

Comment: Hi Jay, yeah you are right it needs to be invoked after the process of webjob. Since, my webjob is containing .Net code, thus, I need to somehow get the callBackUri in my code so that at the end of the code I can invoke it. In my scenario ADF Webhook activity is calling the webjob(which has the .Net app), so in order to invoke the callBackUri first I need to fetch the JSON body from the ADF in my .Net right? this part I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey, since we know that callBackUri need to be invoked at end of the code. And I also do not think you can pass some JSON body value as argument let alone the callBackUri... and if we do this - uri/arguments=callbackuri then the callBackUri is getting passed as a string "callBakcUri" not the JSON body callBackUri,...

Comment: @sabs773 Yes,it is not json,it's string. Don't treat it as json body,it's a string argument.

Comment: @sabs773 But you still could get it in the webjob inside and invoke that uri by yourself. I admit that it's  a little out of callback feature which is supported in the ADF webhook activity.

Comment: @sabs773 Based on the Webjob REST api, the webjob can't accept something like json request body,they only can accept the argument behind the /uri.

Comment: Hi, Can you please try to pass the callBackUri from ADF webhook activity as arguments and see whether it works or not? Thank you...

Comment: @sabs773 I tested it and it works for me. Passed the callbackUri as argument.

Comment: @sabs773 Any further i can do? If you think my answer is beneficial for you,would you please accept it as an answer? Thank you!